# Add a row for missing period and for the corresponding period calculate the average of last 3 Months

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a code which adds missing periods to the dataframe and calculates their respective averages. Refer to the below example:

```
Invoice Date    Amount
9   01/2020 227500
4   02/2020 56000
0   03/2020 22000
1   05/2020 25000
5   06/2020 75000
2   07/2020 27000
6   08/2020 48000
3   09/2020 35000
7   10/2020 115000
8   12/2020 85000
```

In the above dataframe, we see that there's a record missing for '11/2020'. I am trying to add the record for the period of 11/2020 and calculate it's mean for the last three months i.e., if 11/2020 is missing, take the amounts of 12/2020,10/2020 and 9/2020 and calculate its Mean and add/append it to the dataframe.

```
Expected output:
Invoice Date     Amount
10      01/2020  227500.00
4       02/2020   56000.00
0       03/2020   22000.00
5       04/2020   75000.00
1       05/2020   25000.00
6       06/2020   48000.00
2       07/2020   27000.00
7       08/2020  115000.00
3       09/2020   35000.00
8       10/2020   77000.00
11      11/2020   65666.67
9       12/2020   85000.00
```

Please note that, I am able to arrive at the above result with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

FundAdmin = {
    'Invoice Date': ['03/2020', '05/2020', '07/2020', '09/2020', '02/2020', '04/2020', '06/2020', '08/2020', '10/2020', '12/2020',
        '01/2020'
    ],
    'Amount': [22000, 25000, 27000, 35000, 56000, 75000, 48000, 115000, 77000, 85000, 227500]
}

expected_dates = ['01/2020', '02/2020', '03/2020', '04/2020', '05/2020', '06/2020', '07/2020', '08/2020', '09/2020', '10/2020', '11/2020',
    '12/2020'
]

df = pd.DataFrame(FundAdmin, columns = ['Invoice Date', 'Amount'])
current_dates = df['Invoice Date']
missing_dates = list(set(expected_dates) - set(current_dates))
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by = 'Invoice Date')
for i in missing_dates:
    Top_3_Rows = sorted_df.tail(3)# print(Top_3_Rows)
Top_3_Rows_Amount = round(Top_3_Rows.mean(), 2)
CalcDF = {
    'Invoice Date': i,
    'Amount': float(Top_3_Rows_Amount)
}
FullDF = df.append(CalcDF, ignore_index = True)
print(FullDF)
```

However, my code is not able to handle the calculation for missing records in the middle of the dataframe. Meaning, it adds missing period to dataframe, but is not able to pick up the values of the previous 3months and it is adding the same mean amount to all the missing periods. Example: If there's a record for 4/2020 missing, code should be able to add a new record for 4/2020 and assign the value of the mean generated out of 1/2020,2/2020 and 3/2020 to 4/2020. Instead, it is assigning the Mean value of other missing period. Please refer to the below:

```
Expected Output (if both 11/2020 and 4/2020 are missing):

    Invoice Date     Amount
    10      01/2020  227500.00
    4       02/2020   56000.00
    0       03/2020   22000.00
    5       04/2020  101833.33  <---- New Record Inserted for 4/2020 through the calculation the mean for 3/2020,2/2020,1/2020
    1       05/2020   25000.00
    6       06/2020   48000.00
    2       07/2020   27000.00
    7       08/2020  115000.00
    3       09/2020   35000.00
    8       10/2020   77000.00
    11      11/2020   65666.67  <---- New Record Inserted for 11/2020 through the calculation the mean for 12/2020,10/2020,9/2020
    9       12/2020   85000.00

My Output (if both 11/2020 and 4/2020 are missing):

Invoice Date     Amount
10      01/2020  227500.00
4       02/2020   56000.00
0       03/2020   22000.00
5       04/2020   65666.67 <--- Value same as 11/2020
1       05/2020   25000.00
6       06/2020   48000.00
2       07/2020   27000.00
7       08/2020  115000.00
3       09/2020   35000.00
8       10/2020   77000.00
11      11/2020   65666.67 <--- This works fine.
9       12/2020   85000.00
```

From my observation, I found that my code is not able to fetch the last 3 records if the missing period occurs to be in the middle of the dataframe, as I am using tail() method and it is fetching the records of 9/2020,10/2020 and 12/2020, caluclating its mean and assigning the same value to 4/2020. I am a complete beginner to python and if any assistance provided to resolve the above issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you looked at resample? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from random import randint

df_len = 100

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Invoice': [randint(1, 10) for _ in range(df_len)],
    'Dates' : [(datetime.today() - pd.DateOffset(months=mnths_ago)).date() 
               for mnths_ago in range(df_len)],
    'Amount': [randint(1, 100000) for _ in range(df_len)],
})

# Drop 10 random rows
drop_indices = np.random.choice(df.index, 10, replace=False)
df = df.drop(drop_indices)

df

    Invoice       Dates  Amount
0         1  2020-05-19   23797
1         6  2020-04-19   54101
2        10  2020-03-19   91522
3         5  2020-02-19   48762
4         1  2020-01-19   54497
..      ...         ...     ...
93        1  2012-08-19   56834
94       10  2012-07-19   21382
95        2  2012-06-19   33056
96        1  2012-05-19   93336
98        7  2012-03-19   12406

from dateutil import relativedelta

def get_prev_mean(date):
    return df[:df.loc[df.Dates == date].index[0]].tail(3)['Amount'].mean()


r = relativedelta.relativedelta(df.Dates.min(), df.Dates.max())
n_months = -(r.years * 12) + r.months
all_months = [(df.Dates.max() - pd.DateOffset(months=mnths_ago)).date() for mnths_ago in range(n_months)]
missing_months = [mnth for mnth in all_months if mnth in list(df.Dates)]
dct = {mnth: get_prev_mean(mnth) for mnth in missing_months}
to_merge = pd.DataFrame(data=dct.values(), index=dct.keys()).reset_index()
to_merge.columns = ['Dates', 'Amount']
out = pd.concat([df, to_merge], sort=False).sort_values(by='Dates').reset_index(drop=True)
out

     Invoice       Dates   Amount
0        7.0  2012-03-19  12406.0
1        1.0  2012-05-19  93336.0
2        2.0  2012-06-19  33056.0
3       10.0  2012-07-19  21382.0
4        1.0  2012-08-19  56834.0
..       ...         ...      ...
171     10.0  2020-03-19  91522.0
172      NaN  2020-04-19  23797.0
173      6.0  2020-04-19  54101.0
174      NaN  2020-05-19      NaN
175      1.0  2020-05-19  23797.0
```

Comment: Hello there, thanks for taking your time in helping me out. While testing the code posted above, I found that it is not adding the mean value for the missing periods, instead it is adding the mean value for the existing records. Please find my edit to your response for more details :)